# Flash AS3 Error 1120: Access of Undefined Property

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, button

I'm making a game with a pause button. If you die in the game you go to a new frame with a Restart button. I remove the Event Listeners on Frame you land after you die, but it shows "1120: Access of undefined property pauseVenus". It was not a typo. Any Solutions. 
This is my code for the frame with the game which is the 60th frame as it is a game within a virtual world:

```
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVenus);

function pauseVenus(event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop(61);
}
```

Then this is the code for Removing Event Listeners:

```
pause_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVenus);
```

(There are other Event Listeners too. I can remove them without a problem.)The error message is for 'pauseVenus' only. If I remove the line, "pause_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVenus);", it works.. But after you die it gets stuck on the new frame and Flash has to be closed!! Any solutions?
Thank You.

Comment: When you press the button, you will jump to frame number 61. Frame number 61 probably does not have a pause_btn defined, you probably only have it in 60. To solve this, go to the 61st frame in your timeline, add the pause_btn if it doesn't exist and don't forget to set its instance name to "pause_btn" as well.

Comment: Or, another way to solve it would be to remove the event listener **before** you jump to frame 61. This way, a possibly unrelated frame does not need to have a pause_btn in it, just to remove an eventlistener. And when I think about it, this is the best solution, forget my first suggestion.

Comment: that function is defined on a frame and you try to remove it on another frame where it doesn't exist.

Comment: @dodger None of it works...  BTW, It error is for the variable used. Access of undefined property pauseVenus.